# Django UpdateView doesn't get the values of the object and get blank instead

Tags: python, html, mysql, django, web

So I'm creating a django website and I have an Edit Button.
The edit shows a pop up with a few forms to edit. The problem is that the forms to edit are blank! instead of having the previous data. e.g- 
ServerName="Yossi" When I click edit instead of having "Yossi" in the form I have nothing.

What do I need to add to the index.html or the Class of PostEdit so I will have the previous data in the forms and not blank forms?

models.py -

```
from django.db import models
# Create your models here.
class serverlist(models.Model):
        ServerName = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
        Owner = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
        Project = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
        Description = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
        IP = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
        ILO = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
        Rack = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
        Status = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
        #date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

views.py -

```
# Create your views here.

from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.views.generic import TemplateView, UpdateView, DeleteView, CreateView
from DevOpsWeb.forms import HomeForm
from DevOpsWeb.models import serverlist
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
from simple_search import search_filter
from django.db.models import Q
class HomeView(TemplateView):

    template_name = 'serverlist.html'


    def get(self, request):
        form = HomeForm()
        query = request.GET.get("q")
        posts = serverlist.objects.all()

        if query:
            posts = serverlist.objects.filter(Q(ServerName__icontains=query) | Q(Owner__icontains=query) | Q(Project__icontains=query) | Q(Description__icontains=query) | Q(IP__icontains=query) | Q(ILO__icontains=query) | Q(Rack__icontains=query))
        else:
            posts = serverlist.objects.all()
        args = {'form' : form, 'posts' : posts}
        return render(request, self.template_name, args)

    def post(self,request):
        form = HomeForm(request.POST)
        posts = serverlist.objects.all()



        if form.is_valid(): # Checks if validation of the forms passed
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.save()
            text = form.cleaned_data['ServerName']
            form = HomeForm()
            return redirect('serverlist')
        args = {'form': form, 'text': text}
        return render(request, self.template_name,args)

class PostDelete(DeleteView):
    model = serverlist
    success_url = reverse_lazy('serverlist')

class PostEdit(UpdateView):
    model = serverlist
    fields = ['ServerName','Owner','Project','Description','IP','ILO','Rack','Status']
    success_url=reverse_lazy('serverlist')
urls.py -

from django.conf.urls import url, include
from DevOpsWeb.views import HomeView
from DevOpsWeb.views import PostDelete
from DevOpsWeb.views import PostEdit
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = [
    # Examples:
    url(r'^$', HomeView.as_view(), name='serverlist'),

     url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
     #DevOpsWeb:8000/Delete/
     url(r'^delete/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', PostDelete.as_view(), name="delete_post"),
     url(r'^django_popup_view_field/', include('django_popup_view_field.urls', namespace="django_popup_view_field")),
     url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
     #DevOpsWeb:8000/edit/
     url(r'^edit/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', PostEdit.as_view(), name="edit_post"),
```

serverlist.html -

```
                       <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" data-toggle="modal" href="#edit-server-{{server.id}}"
                         data-target="#Edit{{server.id}}"> &nbsp&nbspEdit&nbsp                   <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>
&nbsp


                                                <div id ="Del{{server.id}}" class="modal fade" role="document">
                                                        <div class="modal-dialog" id="delete-server-{{server.id}}">
                                                                        <div class="modal-content">
                                                                                <div class="modal-header">
                                                                                        <h5 class="modal-title">Delete Confirmation</h5>
                                                                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                                                </button>
                                                                                </div>
                                                                                <div class="modal-body">
                                                                                <form action="{% url 'delete_post' server.id %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
                                                                                    <h6>Are you sure you want to delete {{ server.ServerName }}?</h6>
                                                                                                <br>
                                                                                    <center><input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-md" value="Confirm"/>
                                                                                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button></center>

                                                                                </form>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                        </div>


                                                </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-sm" id="Edit{{server.id}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                                <h5 class="modal-title">Edit Server</h5>
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                </button>
                        </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                        <form action="{% url 'edit_post' server.id %}" method="post"> {% csrf_token %}
                                <!--<center>    {{ form.as_p }} </center> -->
                                                        {% for field in form %}
                                                                <div class="fieldWrapper">
                                                {{ field.errors }}
                                                                        <!-- {{ field.label_tag }} -->

                                <small><b>{{ field.html_name }}<p align="left"></b> {{ field }}</small> </p>

                                                {% if field.help_text %}
                                                <p class="help">{{ field.help_text|safe }}</p>
                                                {% endif %}

                                                        </div>


                                {% endfor %}
                                <center><h2> <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-success btn-lg">Confirm</button></h2>
                                <h2><button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button></h2></center>
                                </form>
                        </td>
                        </div>
                </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#updateview

Comment: class AuthorUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Author
    fields = ['name']
    template_name_suffix = '_update_form'

I did the same as they said and still.

Comment: you don't set `template_name` then why you post `index.html`?

Comment: I fixed it. I wanted to do index.html so it will be more easy to understand what is this file but it's serverlist.html

Comment: but there is not template for PostEdit

Comment: It's a modal. Which means when I click the button a pop up shows.
It's in the same template -
<h5 class="modal-title">Edit Server</h5>
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                </button>

Comment: Does anyone have an answer?